# adding image to an array and submit it via curl

Tags: php, post, curl

I've trouble sending image from url to remote host using curl. Everything else works.

```
// assemble full image path

foreach ( $respArr[ 'imgs' ] as $k => $v) {

    $car[ 'photos' ][ $k ] = file_get_contents( 'http://' . $v[ 'ipt' ] . '/im/im-' . $v[ 'ikey' ] ); // full url?

}
```

The issue is that I don't understand how browser sends images, it creates array, than this array content is invisible to me when I try to dump the $_POST.

Any clarification in this area is welcome :)

Comment: Have you tried [using the `CURLFile` class](http://php.net/CURLFile)? or, if you're on a EOL'ed PHP version, using `@'/path/to/file'`?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I'm imitating normal user post from a form. I need to build php array like browser would do and submit it to my api.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem that seems to be the right direction. info is scarce though, and it seems things have changed for php 5.5

Comment: Posted an answer showing how you can use curl to simulate a POST request, submitting a form

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do as follow :

```
$image       = file_get_contents(PATH_TO_IMAGE);
$imageBase64 = base64_encode($image);
```

Now you can transfer the image via curl like an ordinary data
Once, it is transferred, you should use it as follow in your browser

```
print '<img src="data:image/png;base64' . $imageBase64 .'">';
```

**image/TYPE** : you should also transfer the right image type : gif, jpg...

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hi, I don't think this is enough. I'm imitating browser post to a page like a normal user would do using curl.

Answer (score 0):

A crude, but 9/10 times sufficient, approach to simulate a POST-submit using curl would look like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$opts = [
    \CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
    \CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    \CURLOPT_URL            => 'http://your.dom/submit/route',
    \CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    \CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => [
        'image'  => new \CURLFile('/path/to/img.png'),
        //pre 5.5
        'image2' => "@/path/to/img.png",
        //fields like foo[]
        'foo'    => [
            'val1',
            'val2',
            '',//empty
        ],
        'otherField' => '123',
        //fields like user[name] and user[lastName]
        'user'       => [
            'name'     => 'John',
            'lastName' => 'Doe',
        ],
    ]
];
curl_setopt_array($opts);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$debugInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
//error:
$message = curl_error($ch);
$errNr = curl_errno($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

As for using remote images (URL's), you might want to consider constructing [the `tempnam` function](http://php.net/tempnam):

```
//construct file array:
$photos = [];//files you'll add to your curl request
foreach ($files as $v) {
    $tmpFile = tempnam('/tmp/curlfiles');
    //write image to tmp file
    file_put_contents(
        $tmpFile,
        //contents == get the image
        file_get_contents(
            'http://' . $v['ipt'] . '/im/im-' . $v['ikey']
        )
    );
    //add CURLFile resource
    $photos[] = new CURLFile($tmpFile);
    //or $photos[] = "@$tmpFile";...
}
//then, in $opts:
$opts[\CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS]['photos'] = $photos;
//curl_setopt_array && curl_exec etc...
```

On the manual pages for `CURLFile::__construct`, there are some snippets you might be able to use if you don't have `CURLFile` at your disposal, but seeing as you're running 5.5 already, that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: Thanks! but this won't work. Since I'm curling to remote API, remote server receives only tempfile path of the sending server...